# discrod.py как встроить ссылку в эмбед

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, discord.py

мне нужно встроить ссылку в embed, код:

````
emb = discord.Embed(title = "Фото-Редактор", description = f"""```$imgf название фильтра, расширение, картинка - накладывет фильтр на картинку```""""""```$imgf contour png```""" , colour = discord.Color.green())
emb.add_field(name='Фильтры:', value=f"blur\ncontour\ndfsdf\nenhance\{url}\nemboss\nfind_edges\nsmooth\nsmooth_more\nsharpen", inline=True)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так ([стырено](https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/send-an-embed-with-a-discord-bot-in-python-61d34c711046)):

```py
emb = discord.Embed(
    title="Sample Embed", 
    url="https://realdrewdata.medium.com/", 
    description="This is an embed that will show how to build an embed and the different components", 
    color=0xFF5733)
```